# How to format a text-field inside of a table based on its value in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table where one of the columns (`sap.m.Text`) represents a binary value (`0`/`1`) and I would like to format it in the following manner:

1. Mapping: `0`/`1` → `No`/`Yes`
2. Style: `No` should be a red color
3. Style: `Yes` should be a green color

The mapping I've performed as described in [Step 23: Custom Formatters](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de), everything is working correctly.

But I'm struggling with style-formatting. In the [Step 22: Expression Binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/c98d57347ba444c6945f596584d2db45) there is an example how to format a number according to its value by using the `numberState`, however, `sap.m.Text` (`<Text />`) doesn't have such or any similar property.

Is there any easy way to apply a style formatting based on a value for `sap.m.Text`? Or the only way is to apply manually a CSS-style?

Comment: In addition to the linked answer: as mentioned in the Fiori Design Guidelines, either `sap.m.ObjectStatus` or `sap.m.ObjectNumber` can be used if ["you need to display the semantic status of an object"](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/object-display-elements/) (here: the item of the table / list). See also the [UX guideline for Responsive Table (`sap.m.Table`)](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/) which mentions the object display controls.

Comment: PS: please consider closing https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3224

Comment: What's bad to have an ability to specify a `state` for `sap.m.Text` elements?

Comment: How does `sap.m.Text` with `state` differ from `sap.m.ObjectStatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For texts:

```xml
<ObjectStatus
    state = "{= ${isCompleted} === 0 ? 'Error' : 'Success'}"
    text = "{= ${isCompleted} === 0 ? ${i18n>STATUS_NO} : ${i18n>STATUS_YES}}" />
```

For numbers:

```xml
<ObjectNumber
    number = "{= ${isCompleted} === 0 ? ${i18n>STATUS_NO} : ${i18n>STATUS_YES}}"
    state = "{= ${isCompleted} === 0 ? 'Error' : 'Success'}" />
```

Comment: Not sure how much the 2nd snippet makes sense. The `number` should ideally get a number instead of a translatable text

Comment: My initial solution was with `ObjectNumber`, then I realized your solution with `ObjectStatus` and updated the answer. Anyway, I've [proposed](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3224) to the UI5 team to add the `state`-property to `sap.m.Text` in order to avoid extra mess with `ObjectStatus`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by _extra mess_?

Comment: I have a set of `Text`-items in `items`/`ColumnListItem`/`cells`, now I want to add semantic highlight, but to do that I have to replace a `Text`-item with an `ObjectStatus`. While I would expect just to have an ability to provide a `state`-value for the `Text`-item.